# Set default landing page for buddypress member profile

Tags: buddypress

I've been trying to redirect users to the profile page when accessing profiles of users and self. Currently it's redirecting to activity page by default.

> Eg: example.com/members/username

is showing the activity page as default.

I've tried setting the below line in wp-config.php as suggested in [Buddypress forum](https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/change-members-profile-landing-tab/). But doesn't seem to be working.

> define('BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'profile');

Is there any workaround to implement this, instead of profile all the other links(friends, groups, notifications etc.) are working when setting in **BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT**.

Comment: That definition works for me. Are you using a theme builder or youzer or some additional plugin re BuddyPress?  If so, try deactivating them.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've added the constant definition in the right place? As the BuddyPress codex says:

> When adding the code to wp-config.php, place it after
> define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”); and before the authentication keys. If you
> add this line to the bottom of wp-config.php, it will not work.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure Artemy. I also tried creating a **bp-custom.php** there also it's not working. I'm currently facing issue when "profile" is set as BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved when I set the **Activity Streams** Page to **- None -**  in Dashboard->Settings->Buddypress->Pages.

I'm not sure what this setting has to do with the default page. Can someone explain about it?

> site.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=bp-page-settings

[image: Pages Configuration Settings in Buddypress]